# How to write a matrix of $n\times 2$ where the first column is made of only 1's?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

How to write a matrix of $n\times 2$ where the first column is made of only 1's?

Suppose I have a vector x={.24,...,10}.

How can I get this

$\left(
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & .24 \\
    1 & 21 \\
    1 & 33 \\
    1 & 11 \\
    1 & 10
    \end{matrix}\right)$

How can I do that?

Help me please

I know how to write a 'normal' matrix, it's MatrixForm[{1,2},{1,1}] but how to give the form above?

Comment: `ArrayFlatten@{{1, Transpose[{col2}]}}` is another possibility.  Closely related: [Prepend 0 to sublists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7996/106) and [Replace part of the element in a List of points](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/183841/106)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
col2 = {2.4, 21, 33, 11, 10};
Thread[{1, col2}]
```

> {{1, 2.4}, {1, 21}, {1, 33}, {1, 11}, {1, 10}}

```
% // MatrixForm //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 2.4 \\
>  1 & 21 \\
>  1 & 33 \\
>  1 & 11 \\
>  1 & 10 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Also

```
{1, #} & /@ col2 (* or Map[{1, #} &, col2] *)
col1 = ConstantArray[1, Length@col2];
Transpose[{col1, col2}]
```

both give

> {{1, 2.4`}, {1, 21}, {1, 33}, {1, 11}, {1, 10}}

Comment: Many thanks kglr, I think the first option its the easier:)

Comment: @user459663, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, based on Table. For a toy list,

```
bill = Range[5]
Flatten[Table[{1, bill[[j]]}, {i, 1, 1}, {j, 1, 5}], 1]
MatrixForm[ted]
```

The last line is for formating reasons, and Flatten removes a redundant pair of brackets.